# Basic network chat app in Perl

Tags: perl, network-programming

I am trying to write a basic network chat app in Perl for learning purposes. I currently have a server and client program that function almost as I want them to. Multiple clients can connect to the server and send messages to and from it. However, I'm not really sure how to go about sending messages from one client to another and would appreciate a push in the right direction here. Here is the code I have so far, thoughts?

Note: This is my first ever attempt at using networking or using Perl for a proper project so any other guidance on how it's written would also be appreciated.

**chat_server.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# chat_server.pl
use strict;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $port = shift or die "Port required!\n";
my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        LocalPort   => $port,
        Proto       => 'tcp',
        Listen      => SOMAXCONN
    ) or die "Can't create socket: $!!\n";
my $child;

print "Listening for clients on $port...\n";
REQUEST:
while(my $client = $socket->accept) {
    my $addr = gethostbyaddr($client->peeraddr, AF_INET);
    my $port = $client->peerport;

    if($child = fork) {
        print "New connection from $addr:$port\n";
        close $client;
        next REQUEST;
    } die "fork failed!\n" unless defined $child;

    while (<$client>) {
        print "[$addr:$port] says: $_";
        print $client "[$addr:$port] says: $_";
    }   
}
close $socket;
```

**chat_client.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# chat_client.pl
use strict;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $port            = shift or die "No port\n";
my $server          = shift or die "No server\n";
my $client_socket   = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        PeerPort    =>  $port,
        PeerAddr    =>  $server,
        Proto       =>  'tcp'
    ) or die "Can't create send socket: $!!\n";

my $child;

if($child = fork) {
    while(1) {
        sleep(1);
        print scalar <$client_socket>;
    }
}

die "fork failed!\n" unless defined $child;
print "Connected to $server:$port!\n";

do {
    print "> ";
    print $client_socket $_ if defined $_;
} while(<STDIN>);

print "Closing connection";
close $client_socket;
```

Comment: That's actually pretty good for your level of experience. The only thing I would say straight away is that you should make sure your learning material is up to date. `-w` on the command line or shebang line has long been superseded by the superior `use warnings`. You should also declare `$child` in the server code inside the `while`, immediately before the `if`

Answer (score 1):

A single client to a single server isn't too difficult - what you're doing with your code there is - effectively - creating a 1 to 1 relationship. Your `fork`ed server is talking exclusively to your client.

To get information to propagate (via the server) between multiple clients, you're going to have to get a bit more complicated - because you have separate processes, these processes now need to communicate with each other. This is a big enough question that there's a whole segment of the perl documentation about it: [`perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html).

This is actually going to increase the complexity of your code substantially, because you're moving to a 1-to-many relationship on your communications, and they'll all be happening asynchronously.

Socket based communication is one form of inter-process communication (IPC) and you're already doing that. But your 'gotcha' here is that you're moving from 1 to 1 comms to 1 to many comms. You need to be able to broadcast, and this mode of communications doesn't support that particularly well.

What I would suggest is look at [`IO::Pipe`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Pipe.html) - I've some example code here: [How to extract data from Parallel::ForkManager in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533054/how-to-extract-data-from-parallelforkmanager-in-perl/31534111#31534111)

Then use [`IO::Select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Select.html) and `can_read` to asynchronously decide if there's any data coming in on the pipe. You'll probably need an array of pipes - one per client - otherwise you might get concurrent stuff overlapping.

E.g.:

(From `IO::Pipe` doc page:

```
 my $pipe = IO::Pipe->new();
if($pid = fork()) { # Parent
        $pipe->reader();
        while(<$pipe>) {
        ...
        }
    }
    elsif(defined $pid) { # Child
        $pipe->writer();
        print $pipe ...
    }
```

Unfortunately there's a slight gotcha here - your pipes will be created by the forking process, but that in turn means you'll need to figure out how to handle an array of pipe and checking to see if they're readable.

That means you can't sit in a `while` loop around accepting sockets any more - that blocks, so you'd have messages queued until another client connects (which is really not going to be what you want). So you'll also need to use `select` again to check whether there's something ready to `accept` first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, to be honest, I'm still extremely confused about how to implement this. Could I still do this with only one process per connection or would I need to fork again? How could I pass a data packet recieved from one connection to all the open connections? I had an idea though; say I had each forked process listening for data, once one recieved some data, I could use a list shared between all processes containing all living connections (although I'm unsure of how to do this, or if it's even possible), and just loop through all the connections and send it like that. Thoughts?

Comment: Harder than it sounds because sharing lists via fork is hard. Threads can though.

Comment: Same conclusion I came to, could you elaborate slightly on how I could use threads here?

Comment: Too much to fit in the comments. But threads::shared let you share a data structure.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try and implement that now :)

Comment: One last question - just to clarify, can what I'm trying to be do be done in an easier fashion using only threads and no forks, or do I need a combination of the two?

Comment: Never mix the two. That way lies madness. Forks and pipes work. Threads and shared memory do too. Both makes a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Although thinking about it, you don't actually need either. You can do non blocking reads on sockets, and do it that way. That might be easier overall,  too.

Comment: I know this might be a fairly big ask, but could you modify your main answer to include a paragraph or two on how I might do it implement this other way? I'd really appreciate it

Comment: Not easily - but I can point you at an example: http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Select.html Scroll to the bottom, and you can see a socket based scenario.